# Will Bluetooth hands-free drivers be installed if BT stack doesn't support A2DP?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bluetooth, broadcom

I have a hands-free device which has no problems being paired with windows and I can set it to be the default sound output device, I don't actually hear anything on the unit, but it worked fine with GNU/Linux and with my mobile phone.

From what I can see, the cause of that is usually a problem with Bluetooth stack. I think that I have Broadcom Bluetooth stack installed, so it should be working but it isn't.

To make things better, my Bluetooth radio is integrated into my laptop and manufacturer isn't providing drivers for it and Broadcom itself recently pulled support, so I can't just reinstall the stack to make sure I have newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is yes.  Drivers were automatically installed even on Microsoft's stack.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. In my case, the basic drivers were installed but the A2DP drivers got installed only after detection of the A2DP device

Comment: @Sathya♦  I'll have to check if A2DP device showed up or not.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php

Comment: Yes and it doesn't support my device anymore.